# What is this $\Sigma_4 /\langle (12)(34)\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question that I am supposed to answer is

> Are the orbits $\Sigma_4 /\langle (12)(34)\rangle$ and $\Sigma_4 /\langle (13)(24)\rangle$ isomorphic as $\Sigma_4$ sets?

I do not understand what $\Sigma_4 /\langle (12)(34)\rangle$ is in this contex.

Definition of orbit that I know is:

> If $x \in X$ (where $X$ is a set) and $G$ is a group then
> $\operatorname{orb} (x) = \{ \varphi_g(x) : g \in G \}$

So I understand that I can have orbit of an element but what is this $\Sigma_4 /\langle(12)(34)\rangle$ then?

Comment: Would you please define $\sum_4$?

Comment: The $G/H$ is the $G$-set of the left cosets of $H$: $g\cdot kH=gk H$ - for every group $G$ and its subgroup $H$.

Comment: $\sum_4$ is a permutation group

Comment: *a permutation group* should be *the group of permutations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$*

Comment: Use [the fact described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2283624/11619).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $\Sigma_4$ is the symmetric group on four symbols, the notation

$$\Sigma_4 /\langle (12)(34)\rangle$$

means the set of $\Sigma_4$ left cosets of the subgroup $\langle (12)(34)\rangle$ of $\Sigma_4$ generated by the element $(12)(34)$.

---

For a more specific definition involving actions, see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action):

> The set of all orbits of $X$ under the action of $G$ is written as X/G (or, less frequently: G\X), and is called the *quotient* of the action.

Comment: Ok, but can It be considered as an orbit?

Comment: It is not just the quotient, it is a $G$-set. So $G$ acts on it, and there are orbits of this action.

Comment: I have edited the question, @kombucza.